# Invalid number of arguments error for getter function with no passed arguments

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging

I am receiving this error when trying to call the `getUsers` getter function from the contract below: `Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function`. Running on Truffle in develop mode.

```
mapping (address => User) Users;
address[] usersByAddress;

struct User {
    string handle;
    bytes32 city;
    bytes32 state;
    bytes32 country;
}

function registerNewUser(string handle, bytes32 city, bytes32 state, bytes32 country) returns (bool success) {
    address thisNewAddress = msg.sender;
    if(bytes(Users[msg.sender].handle).length == 0 && bytes(handle).length != 0){
        Users[thisNewAddress].handle = handle;
        Users[thisNewAddress].city = city;
        Users[thisNewAddress].state = state;
        Users[thisNewAddress].country = country;
        usersByAddress.push(thisNewAddress);  
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;       
    }
  }

//getters
function getUsers() view returns (address[]) { return usersByAddress; }

function getUser(address userAddress) view returns (string, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32) {
    return (Users[userAddress].handle, Users[userAddress].city, Users[userAddress].state, Users[userAddress].country);
}
```

Let's say you deploy this contract in Truffle develop testnet and get an instance of the object `x`. I can create a user by sending the transaction `x.registerNewUser("Bob123","Orlando","FL","USA")`. Then I run `x.getUser(web3.eth.accounts[0])` and get the following array:

[ 'Bob123',
  '0x4f726c616e646f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x464c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x5553410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ]

This is expected since the last 3 elements in the array are type `bytes32`. I expect `x.getUsers` or `x.getUsers.call()` to return an array of one address (my address at `web3.eth.accounts[0]`) but instead get the `invalid Solidity arguments` error even though there are no arguments passed into `getUsers`.

Comment: Please provide the code where you call getUser

Comment: I edited the question with the code I use to register a user and to call the `getUser` and `getUsers` functions.

Comment: This is definitely a Truffle issue - your code runs sweetly in Remix. There are some issues on the [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/596)  and [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1043) GitHubs about this with suggested solutions - worth trying. Let us know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @benjaminion for those links, deleting the artifacts in /build prevents the error from showing up.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
x.getUser.call(web3.eth.accounts[0],{from: 'YOUR ADDRESS'}, function (error, result) {
    console.log('error ' + error);
    console.log('result ' + result);
});
```

Comment: There aren't any issues with getting the `getUser()` function to work. As stated in my question it's the `getUsers()`. The only way I could get it to work was what @benjaminion suggested is delete the artifacts in the /build, migrate --reset, and new artifacts will be written in /build which then prevents errors from showing up when you call `getUsers()`.